ADF Copy Activity Log
there.
I am trying to find out the reason for my failed pipeline. The generic MS message seems to point to a data issue.
It is loading Synapse from a set of parquet files.
I have turned on logging (warning) but the two text files mentioned in the MS documentation are empty.
There is a _rejectedrows ADF created with other text files (*error.txt and *Row.txt) but I am not sure how to read them. The documentation does not even mention those. They seem to be showing the rows processed.
Please advise.
Thanks.
Turned on logging and expected some useful info in the logs pointing to the root cause of the failure


I am trying to find out the reason for my failed pipeline. The generic MS message seems to point to a data issue.

You have enabled logging which will save the data for skipped rows or incompatible rows for copying. it will store the data in blob storage or datalake storage where if your file size is greater than 4 MB you need to download it and then you will be able to read the files

Also check your parquet file as you are getting data issue error.
Check for any inconsistencies, malformed data, or missing columns that might be causing the loading process to fail.
Make sure to the data types and schema defined in the parquet files don't have mismatches between the schema and the data can lead to errors.

